# Ruby on Rails finding User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with part of my site, related to this line (in agreement_controller.create):

```
@user = User.find(params[:agreement][:user2_id])
```

The error I get is that it can't find the user without an id.  I tried `@user = User.find(params[:id])` and `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` with the same result.  I don't really know why this wouldn't work or where to start looking (I'm a bit inexperienced with RoR), so any tips are helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Hard to figure out whats going wrong without code. However, you can try to debug your code by writing params to the logger to figure out whats in there. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Have you tried to puts user_id is getting or not. Also you can try User.find_by_id(params[:id])

Comment: you write raise params.inspect on the top of the method. or show us the view page.

Comment: @slykat - Thanks, I'll try that.  I'm not sure where it's going wrong, so I didn't know what code to post.  I'll try to get working with the debugger.

Comment: @SandipKaranjekar - I'm not sure how to use "puts" (searching for it in documentation just gives lots of "inputs" and "outputs") - can you explain or link me to some documentation?

Comment: @vijikumar - Putting `raise params.inspect` at the top of the method gives a runtime error (I don't think that's supposed to happen), but also lists the parameters that are being passed in.  Those parameters don't include `user_id` or `id`, so my guess would be that the id simply isn't being passed in from wherever it's called?  I'd thought Rails did it automatically.

Comment: paste the runtime error content

Comment: in that error message we can see the params.

Comment: i think params for PUT/POST requests are logged by default in rails.. you should just be able to watch the server logs as your fire off the request and catch the parameters there.

Comment: Can use the following code and paste the result

raise params.inspect    (before your above code )

Answer (score 0):

The only sure thing is that `params[:agreement]` is a hash with `nil` as value for `:user2_id` key, or a hash without this key at all. What may be a problem or not depends on your view (and maybe on your model because `user2` seems a strange name for an association).

In your HTML, you should have an input with `agreement[user2_id]` as `name`, and this input should be submitted.